# where is the code generated by visual studio controls editor for visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dialog, generated-code

When I make a dialog with visual c++ editor, I would see the code generated by my editor to make the window components..It's possible? When I double-click on a component, I see only the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls/components of a Dialog Box are described in a Resource Template, in a RC file. In the Solution Explorer, right click on the RC file in "Resource Files" and then choose "Open with..." and select "C++ Code Editor".

The link between the content of the RC file and the C++ code creating the Dialog Box at Run Time is done via the [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434.aspx) API, or one of his cousin, as [CreateDialogParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645445.aspx).

Comment: cool!can I insert my code here or it's not compiled by "standard" c++ compiler?

Comment: I would insert every ID Component into an array or other data structure

Comment: The RC file is a static description of the your Dialog Box as a collection of windows controls. No C++ code here. You could enumerate all child windows of your Dialog Box in it's WM_INITDIALOG

Comment: and if I would that, for example, every TextBox created is a child of a my personal subclass of TextBox? For example, I would override the mousemove method of a textbox generated from the editor

Comment: What you want is possible, either by subclassing oy by registering your own class. Discussion about that won't fit in a comments thread :-)